# calling a function from JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have this piece of code. I want to add some commands so that the table board from `drawgrid` shows up alongside with the 'konichiwa' in the `JPanel` thing. I've tried using some commands found on google i.e. `JTable table = new JTable(rec, header);`. I haven't been able to find other ways of implementing the table into the panel so if anybody can suggest a command that might work.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

@SuppressWarnings({"serial", "unused"})
public class OnO extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        int i = yesno("Play game? D:");
        if (i == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("WELCOME!"); // initializes objects from class JFrame
            JLabel label1 = new JLabel("konichiwa"); // initializes objects from class JLabel
            f.add(label1); // f calls the add function
            f.pack(); // f calls the pack function
            JTable table = new JTable(d);
            f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
            f.add(table);
            f.setSize(550, 400);
            f.setVisible(true); // f calls the set visible function
            // when program gets big, need a way to route
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static int yesno(String theMessage) {
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, theMessage,
                "WELCOME", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        return result;
    }

    public static String drawgrid() {
        String s = null;
        int[][] board = new int[16][16];
        int i;
        int j;
        Random r = new Random();
        int low = 0;
        int high = 2;
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                int result = r.nextInt(high - low) + low;
                board[i][j] = result;
            }
        }

        for (int[] row : board) {
            printRow(row);
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static void printRow(int[] row) {
        for (int i : row) {
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the game Ono, but if it's like Chess or Checkers it might be better to use a standard panel with a `GridLayout`. Then it can determine its own size and be added using a `CardLayout` at start-up along with a blank panel that shows initially. Then the app flips to that card once the game begins. It would be helpful to develop a game model (e.g. `OnoModel`) that is used as information to set the visual state of the `OnoBoard` (or whatever), That makes 'new game' easy - simply reset the model or create a fresh one. Avoid things like `f.setSize(550, 400);`. It's a guess.

Comment: `JTable table = new JTable(d);` BTW - I could ask *"What's a `d`"* because it's not defined in the code shown, but instead I'll advise: 1) Use meaningful attribute (method and class) names that describe what they are. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: At least part of the problem lies in these three lines of code: `f.add(label1); .. f.add(new JScrollPane(table)); f.add(table);`. Firstly, when a component (like a `JTable`) is added to a scroll pane, only the scroll pane should be added to the GUI. Secondly, in the case of a `JFrame`, the content pane will have a `BorderLayout` and adding something to a border layout with no constraint will default to adding it to the `CENTER` which can only display one component. Try instead adding the `JLabel label1` to `LINE_START` or similar. `pack()` should be called *after* components are added.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the reply! This works so much better. However, my goal is to create a board where the numbers are randomly generated between 0 and 1. I'm still tinkering through the codes but I hope I am able to do this! Thanks again.

Comment: *"This works so much better."* Which 'this'? Given I wrote 3 separate comments crammed with advice and tips, now is the time for more words / detail, not less. *"However.."* Nothing that I commented, *nothing*, would make it impossible to create 'numbers randomly generated between 0 and 1'! *"I'm still tinkering"* Well if you reach a point where you're stuck, be sure to [edit] to add a [mre] before asking more questions. Also make it clear *where* you're stuck as I had to make guesses to add the comments I did and my patience for guessing is very low.

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry about not being clear! I meant the `GridLayout` part. Actually, about ten minutes ago I managed to figure out the code for the table of numbers generating between 0 and 1! You've been so helpful I can't thank you more!!